# Can I view debug level logging output in Visual Studio 2010 for my local running asp.net mvc 3 app?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I've been working with IntelliJ and Grails for the past year or so but am now on a Visual Studio 2010 and ASP.NET MVC 3 project. With the former, I get a console window with all kinds of debug information including SQL generated by GORM and stack traces as they happen with trivial configuration. Now, it's been a couple years since I've worked on an ASP.NET app (WebForms back then) but I don't remember anything like that in Visual Studio. Is there any way to view real-time debug logging output including LINQ-to-SQL generated statements, significant web server events (currently using the built-in development server), and stack traces when the occur?

Thanks.

Comment: The closest I have seen in a single package/plugin is IntelliTrace (only available in VS2010 Ultimate). I'm quite curious to see what other recommendations people have.

Comment: comes out the box with Mono, another nice feature of an IDE that otherwise plays catchup to VS (performance on Linux is incredible as well..). In reality (as of today) you'll need Windows/VS for the latest & greatest in .NET, so no console convenience a la Java, or better, Groovy, where a simple println does wonders. @Stephan, curious, why did you leave Grails & GORM and return to .NET?

Comment: Hi @virtualeyes, thanks for the Mono insight. re: JVM -> .NET, I'm simply on a new project at work (we build custom business applications on either platform based on customer requirements, and I like to work on both to keep things interesting). But I have to admit, I'm excited to be working with ASP.NET MVC 3 + LINQ-to-SQL + C# + F#. Grails is a great web framework, but ASP.NET MVC 3 is compelling too (It's clean and has some nice features, but I do miss certain grails features). What I'm really excited about is LINQ-to-SQL; *it's blowing my mind*. And also F#, my personal favorite language.

Comment: LINQ is the main reason I have ventured into .NET.  MVC3 + Razor + Script# are very, very nice features as well. That EVERYTHING is strongly typed is pretty much unreal. I have tried to get going with Grails several times, but mostly I just feel constrained, unlike Groovy where it's quite easy to roll-your-own (GSQL, JSON, proxy-able POGOs, MOP, closures, it's all right there).  Strong typing is the kicker though, with Groovy you can go down the rabbit hole without the IDE having a clue where you (your code) went ;-)

Comment: @virtualeyes: indeed! I tried to dampen my enthusiasm a bit since I saw that LAMP, JVM, and dynamic languages have been your forte. But I am truly astonished at how advanced and productive the .NET line-up has become. Combining type inference ("local" on the C# side, super powerful Hindley-Milner on the F# side) with code as data (C# Expression Trees, F# Quotations) has very solidly tipped my favoritism from dynamic to statically typed languages (and of course, C# and F# both have language-level features to facilitate dynamic programming when appropriate).

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you will depend on several tools to accomplish this task, take for example SQl-Profile to see the exact SQL queries as they run.

For web page events and real time performance statistics, you can rely on "ASP.NET Tracing"

this is from Microsoft Official documentation :

> If you want trace information to
> appear at the end of the page that it
> is associated with, set the trace
> element's pageOutput attribute to
> true. If you want tracing information
> to be displayed only in the trace
> viewer, set the pageOutput attribute
> to false.

By adding the following block of code to your web.config, you will be able to see many performance statistics that you will enjoy looking at.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trace enabled="true" pageOutput="true" requestLimit="40" localOnly="false"/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

this will append real-time tracing information at the end of every page you visit.

For debugging information, you can give Intelli-Trace a try.

it's a VS2010 new feature that allows you to collect debugging information while you use the website, this may describe it better than me:

> IntelliTrace
> collects data about a managed
> application in the background,
> including information from many
> framework components such as ADO.NET,
> ASP.NET and System.XML. These
> IntelliTrace events allow the
> developer to see what has previously
> occurred during execution, and most
> importantly, to “step back in time” to
> see prior states of the application
> without having to restart the
> debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Mohammed - turns out asp.net tracing doesn't totally work in mvc (specifically appending trace to response stream). but that led me to find Glimps and Elmah, which are giving me some good info so far (Elmah gives me stack traces, Glimps gives asp.net mvc info). SQL Profiler does the job on the SQL side indeed, thanks for that. IntelliTrace looks awesome, but unfortunately we only have the Premium edition of VS. i wonder why the VS / .NET picture here is so complicated compared to IntelliJ / Java.

Comment: I've used both Glimps and and ELMAH and I can assure you that you gonna love them.